# CameraCapture Windows8.1 and WP 8.1 disable system sound when CapturePhotoToStreamAsync

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is any way to disable system camera sound when I do next:

```
var  _capture = new MediaCapture();
await _capture.InitializeAsync();
await _capture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);//phone play system camera shot sound, I need disable this
```

Comment: Camera shutter sound is a System Settings - the user can switch it off from settings. As many other system settings are not available for 3rd party apps, I think in case will be the same - user will have to switch it off manully from settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. MediaCapture just calls the default camera app of the phone so it's up to that application to configure the sound (Nokia Camera could be launched for example). 
A possible workaround would be to lower the system volume before capturing and the turning the volume back up. However, as a user I wouldn't like that.